# How to fix the position of elements to a page?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have this image currently. The circle, the close image, and get your quotes image. **(see below)**

[Correct image layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPOv0.png)

I can't get all elements to be fixed together so when I change the size of the screen the elements move together instead of separately across the page. **(see below)**

[Incorrect image layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwoRn.png)

I have looked into the positioning of each element, but I maybe misunderstanding something, or my code is messy. Please see below:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
            <!--Thanks for visiting image-->
                <div id="thanks-for-visiting-img-bg" class="thanks-for-visiting-bg">
                    <div id="thanks-for-visiting-img-container" class="thanks-for-visiting-img-container">
                        <img src="../images/thanks_for_visiting_img.png" alt="Thanks for visiting" id="thanks-for-visiting-img" class="thanks-for-visiting-img">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Get Quotes button-->
                <div>
                    <img src="../images/btn.png" alt="Get Your Quotes" id="get-quotes-btn" class="get-quotes-btn">
                </div>
                <!--Close button-->
                <div>
                    <img src="../images/close_green.png" alt="Close Thanks For Visiting image" id="close-btn" class="close-btn">
                </div>
            
    </body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*CONTAINER*/

.thanks-for-visiting-img-container {
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
    z-index: 2147483647;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
    position: fixed !important;
    cursor: default !important;
}

/*IMAGE BACKGROUND*/

.thanks-for-visiting-bg {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*z-index: 2147483647;*/
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.83;
}


/*-- GET QUOTES BUTTON --*/

.get-quotes-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 288px;
    height: 49px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: auto;
    left: -20px;
    top: 425px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

.close-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 65%;
    top: 80px;

}
```

**.thanks-for-visiting-img-container** and **.thanks-for-visiting-bg** has to be fixed because the bg class' CSS doesn't work without it and the img container has to be fixed because the page will need to scroll underneath it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the `div` tags (Get Quotes, the image and the close button) in another `div` tag and then, add this CSS class to that new `div` tag:

```
.mainClass {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```